# Bevel is flipped

Tags: modeling

I'm using bevel on a curve but it keeps coming in reversed.

- I tried adjusting the tilt on both objects.
- I tried messing with the Transform Orientations a bit.
- I've redrawn everything.
- Is there a better way to sweep a rail?

[image: evil bevel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into edit mode of the your bezier curve (not the one used as bevel object).

Switch direction by pressing: <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>D</kbd>